# Python, Scipy: Odeint invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style, modeling

The following is a code I'm writing to solve the Fermi-Pasta-Ulam-Tsingou problem to Model the behavior of a chain of particles. 
the thing that the equation depends on the initial condition of the nearest neighbors in addition the main particles:

I have defined the variables before and I have issue with working Odeint and vectors:

```
def FPUT(y, t):
    for j in N:
        u1, u2 = y
        dydt = [u2[j], -( k( u1[j+2] + u1[j] - 2*u1[j+1]) * ( 1 + alpha( u1[j+2] - u1[j] ) ))]
return u1,dydt
```

.

```
y0 = [0,0] 
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
```

.

```
sol = odeint(FPUT, y0, t)
```

I have the following error for running the code:

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

[error description screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtrGy.png)

please help, I am clueless on how to solve this.

if you need more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Pasta%E2%80%93Ulam%E2%80%93Tsingou_problem